# Script setValue based on the values of two columns for each row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, switch-statement

I'm working on a Google Sheets document in which I calculate profits based on two columns: Price and payment method.
I'd like help with a script that checks the values of said columns in each row, and based on those two columns sets a certain value in another column (net profit).

So:
`If` row 2 `column E` (price) = €47,00 && `column H` (payment menthod) = "iDEAL" `then` set the value in `column K` (net profit) of row 2 to €42,98.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpWKX.png)

This table has 3 different price values: €47, €37,9 and €28,20.
We offer four different payment methods: "iDEAL", "PayPal", "Bancontact" and "Creditcard".

For each combination of price value and payment method, there is a different net profit.
[Net profit values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZgAK.png)

I tried to edit the following script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var s = sheetActive.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if( r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == 47)
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
      nextCell.setValue(42.89);
}
```

Based on the script in this link: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/how-do-i-update-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-using-a-script

But I didn't get it to work and it also doesn't take the values of two columns into account.

I also found the following script: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133430/use-setvalue-to-update-a-column-based-on-values-of-two-others-that-match-their

But I haven't been able to find out how to edit the script to fit my needs.

I have minimal experience with scripting and programming but I think I need a for-loop that iterates through my rows in combination with a case/switch based on two column values.

Please help me out and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## **APPS SCRIPT:**

#### [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

- runs the function automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet.

I think it is not desirable to run a loop for checking and setting of net profit values every time you modify a cell in the sheet.

You can either run a function manually in the Apps Script Editor or [run a script from a button](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26326035?hl=en) whenever you want to update the net profit values.

**Here is a sample code:**

```
var netProfit = [
    //47,00
    {"iDEAL":'€ 42,89',
     "PayPal": '€ 41,09',
     "Creditcard": '€ 42,25',
     "Bancontact": '€ 42,81'},
    //37,60
    {"iDEAL":'€ 34,27',
     "PayPal": '€ 32,47',
     "Creditcard": '€ 33,63',
     "Bancontact": '€ 34,19'},
    //28,20
    {"iDEAL":'€ 25,64',
     "PayPal": '€ 23,84',
     "Creditcard": '€ 25,00',
     "Bancontact": '€ 25,56'},
  ];

function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 47,00'){
    sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[0][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
  }else if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 37,60'){
    sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[1][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
  }else if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 28,20'){
    sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[3][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
  }
}

function updateProfit(){

  //Select the sheet where you want to update
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var row = 2;

  for(row; row<=sheet.getLastRow(); row++ ){
    if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 47,00'){
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[0][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
    }else if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 37,60'){
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[1][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
    }else if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()=='€ 28,20'){
      sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue(netProfit[2][sheet.getRange(row,2).getValue()]);
    }
  }
  
}
```

- If you still want to pursue onEdit() trigger, I included a sample code as well (just remove it if you decide not use it). What it does is get the current row where a cell was modified using  `e.range.getRow()`, get the price value of the current row using `sheet.getRange(row,1).getValue()`, then set the net profit column using `sheet.getRange(row,3).setValue()`. I used an array of objects to map the payment method per price where price € 47,00 pertains to array `netProfit[0][payment method]` and so on. This will only update the net profit row of the cell that is being modified.
- Another option is to loop all rows and update the net profit using `updateProfit()`.Same checking done, the only difference with the onEdit() trigger is that it will check and update all net profit within the sheet that is selected. You can combine this function with the onEdit() trigger if you want to update all net profit every time a cell was changed or [run a script from a button](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/26326035?hl=en)

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

## **FORMULA:**

I also tried to look for possible solution using formula but for this one, you might need to create a lookup table for net profit with this format.

[image]

**Formula:**

```
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A10&B2:B10,{A16:A27&B16:B27,C16:C27},2,0))," ")
```

[ARRAYFORMULA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) lets you perform a non-array function in each array of rows.

[VLOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) lets you search for a key from a range of values and return the value of a specific cell in the row found.

We used VLOOKUP() to search for Price and Payment method in the range selected. This will return a net profit value provided in column C. We used ARRAYFORMULA() to perform this vlookup() in each row from the range selected.